# Visualizing netCDFs xarray

Tags: python, plot, netcdf, python-xarray

[image]

[image]

*Hello everyone.In the picture you can see a sample of my code(it repeats for i==6),and the outputs.Can somone tell me how to add coastlines/boundaries to maps?"ax.coastlines() failed. Thank you*

Comment: Keeo in mind to share your code as text within a code tag. You can see how it works in the answer below and please read the guidelines for how to ask a question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your axes is not a geoAxes. To make it a geoAxes you have to tell matplotlib what projection (e.g. PlateCarree) you would like to use.

What you could do is using the cartopy library and adding the projection key word to your subplot. See example below:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Create sample data
lon = np.arange(129.4, 153.75+0.05, 0.25)
lat = np.arange(-43.75, -10.1+0.05, 0.25)
data = 10 * np.random.rand(len(lat), len(lon))
data_array = xr.Dataset({"DC": (["lat", "lon"], data),
                 'DMC': (["lat", "lon"], data),
                 'FFMC': (["lat", "lon"], data)},
                 coords={"lon": lon,"lat": lat})

# Just checking the datasets are not empty
print(data_array)


#< Plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=3, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()}) # Use PlateCarree projection
data_array['DC'].plot(ax=axes[0,0], cmap='Spectral_r', add_colorbar=True, extend='both')
axes[0,0].coastlines() # Add coastlines
```